# Adding Objective C compiler to GCC 4.7.2

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, gcc

I finished building the GCC 4.7.2 with C, C++ and Go compilers on my Ubuntu 12.04. I now want to add the Objective C compiler, is it possible to add it to the previous build? If so, how should i proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Install the GNU Objective-C Runtime using `sudo apt-get install gobjc` and compile your objective c code using `gcc -o <filename> <filename>.m -Wall -lobjc`,  `-Wall` and `-o` are optional. The key argument is `-lobjc`. Then use `./<filename>` to launch exec

Comment: Thanks Harish, but the 'apt-get' is pulling the 'gobjc-4.6' package while i would like to have the latest package, should i add a ppa? Also will building gcc again on the current  build but this time after including Objective C sort the problem?

Comment: add `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and run `sudo apt-get update` and install `gobjc4.7`.Thanks

Comment: i will try this, but is it possible to add to the existing build using the 'gcc' source which i already have?